# scanf produces segfault when the program is run with a custom entry point (using gcc 7.4.0)

Tags: c, gcc

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("main\n");
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}

int main1() {
    printf("main1\n");
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}

int main2() {
    printf("main2\n");
    int a = getchar() - '0';
    int b = getchar() - '0';
    int c = getchar() - '0';
    printf("a = %d\n", 100 * a + 10 * b + c);
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming that the code resides in a file called test.c, the following works fine (it prints "a = 123"):

```
gcc -o test test.c
echo 123 | ./test
```

If, however, I run the program with a custom entry point, I get the dreaded Segmentation fault:

```
gcc -o test test.c -e"main1"
echo 123 | ./test
```

But if I replace the scanf with three getchars, the program runs fine again despite being run with a custom entry point:

```
gcc -o test test.c -e"main2"
echo 123 | ./test
```

To make things even more interesting, these problems occur with gcc 7.4.0 but not with gcc 4.8.4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

The `-e` command line flag redefines the *actual* entry point of your program, not the “user” entry point. By default, using GCC with the GNU C standard library (glibc) this entry point is called `_start`, and it performs further setup before invoking the user-provided `main` function.

If you want to replace this entry point and continue using glibc you’ll need to perform further setup yourself. But alternatively you can use the following method to replace the `main` entry point, which is much simpler:

```sh
gcc -c test.c
objcopy --redefine-sym main1=main test.o
gcc -o test test.o
```

Note, this will only work if you *don’t* define `main` in your code, otherwise you’ll get a “multiple definition of `main'” error from the linker.

Comment: The question remains though, why it did work with GCC 4.8.4

Comment: @marcolz Probably because GCC 4.8.4 (which is ancient!) used a different version of glibc, where `scanf` happens to work (or even just *seems* to work) without requiring further initialisation.